# How can i animate a list menu vertically using translateY or marquee?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to replicate the same animation menu as this page: https://newland.tv/directors, using translateY property in css , 
i achieved something quite similar pretty much using marquee , but theres a big gap between the end and the beginning of the animation. 
Here's my code example

```
<marquee bahavior="scroll" direction ="up">  

<ul class="m">

   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>

</ul>

</marquee>
```

and this is the css :

```
.marquee {
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    border: 2px solid #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    margin: 200px auto;
}

 @keyframes marquee {
    0% { down: 0; }
    100% { down: -100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use translateX with infinite animation;

```js
.container{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:200px
}

.content{
  height:100%;
  animation: 3s linear up infinite
}

@keyframes up{
  from{transform:translateY(-100%)}
  to{transform:translateY(100%)}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<ul class="m">
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>
   <li>1. - http://afrika-agency.com/ ijzzejrzerjfp^</li>

</ul>

</div>
</div>
```